# Определение клика на динамически созданном элементе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такой код срабатывает не на всех элементах:

```
$('body').click(function (event) {
    t=event.target||event.srcElement; 
         alert(t.tagName);
});
```

Нужен более надежный метод

Comment: Приведённый пример должен работать без проблем (за исключением того, что jQuery был как раз создан для того, чтобы абстрагировать пользователя от браузерных расхождений, поэтому нет смысла определять target руками). Сделайте пример на jsfiddle и объясните, в каких ситуациях приведённый код у вас не работает. Вполне возможно, что какой-то другой обработчик перехватывает событие и запрещает его всплытие.

Comment: [Документация](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `$(element).on('click', function (event) { ... });`

Answer (score 3):

Через [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click) элемент уже найден в DOM, а через [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) jquery ищет при каждом клике указанный `.b` элемент

```js
element = $("<button class='b'>element</button>");

$('button').click(function() {
  $('body').append(element);
});

$('body').on('click', '.b', function() {
  console.log('b click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<button>Создать элемент</button>
```

Comment: А чем .click() от .on() отличается в этом разрезе? Чем ваш вариант делегирования отличается от того, что привёл автор в вопросе?

Comment: @АлексейУколов, в теории через `.click()` элемент уже найден в DOM. А через `.on()` jquery ищет при каждом клике указанный `.b` элемент.

Comment: .click() - это обёртка над .on(). В вопросе ненужная реализация делегирования, но в целом то же самое, что и .on('click', '.class', handler)

Comment: Точно не знаю, почему так происходит, но @Doofy прав, поскольку, если элемент был добавлен в DOM после загрузки скрипта с методом .click(), то .click() не сработает, будет работать только $('body').on('click')